# Extract data from a column based on another column in df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following df without the choice_text column. I want to add the new column 'choice_text' which extracts the value in column 3 before ":" based on the number in column 2. So if choice is 1 then choice_text shows 15 mins.

| ID | Choice | Options | Choice_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3 |  |
| Y | 2 | 15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3 |  |
| Z | 3 | 15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3 |  |

Comment: Please post your data the output from the command `dput(your_dataframe)` so we can access your data more easily. Also include any code you've tried and/or errors you've gotten.

Comment: Add also the expected output

Comment: @LMc, I've been cheating a little by using alistaire's [`read.md`](https://github.com/alistaire47/read.so/blob/master/R/md.R) on the markdown table embedded here. Granted, it requires editing the question in order to get to the pipe-based markdown table, but it's far easier than `read.table` in this case.

Comment: @r2evans Awesome! Thanks for taking the time to share that tip since these markdown tables are posted quite often.

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```r
trimws(gsub(":.*", "",
  mapply(`[`, strsplit(df$Options, ","), df$Choice)
))
# [1] "15 mins" "30 mins" "45 mins"
```

(This has been fixed so that if `Choice` is ever larger than the number of `Options`, it will return `NA` instead of failing.)

Walk-through:

- `strsplit` splits the strings by `,`, resulting in a nested list (3-long, 1 for each row) each with 3 substrings (in this case, this 3 is different than `nrow(df)` 3);
- the `mapply(.)` portion does a "zipping" of the options; for instance, the `mapply` line is equivalent to:

  ```r
  o <- strsplit(df$Options, ",")
  c(
    o[[1]][ df$Choice[1] ],
    o[[2]][ df$Choice[2] ],
    o[[3]][ df$Choice[3] ]
  #       ^^ this `[` is what the first argument to `mapply` is referring
  )
  ```
- `gsub` removes the `:` and beyond;
- `trimws` cleans up surround blank-space

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all` which is vectorized to extract the digits (`\\d+`) followed by the 'mins' and `:` along with the 'Choice' column values by `paste`ing the pattern with the 'Choice' column, then remove the suffix part with `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Choice_text = str_remove(str_extract(Options,
        str_c("\\d+ mins: ",  Choice)), ":\\s+\\d+$"))
```

-output

```
#  ID Choice                            Options Choice_text
#1  X      1 15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3     15 mins
#2  Y      2 15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3     30 mins
#3  Z      3 15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3     45 mins
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("X", "Y", "Z"), Choice = 1:3, 
  Options = c("15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3", 
"15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3", "15 mins: 1, 30 mins: 2, 45 mins: 3"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I like this solution very much. I have two questions I hope you could help me clarify, (1) why do you use `str_extract_all` rather than `str_extract`? And (2) why do you add the `$` and the end of the pattern input to `str_remove`?

Comment: @WilliamGram 1) Sorry, I could have used `str_extract` as it is just for extracting one element (updated). 2). The `$` in regex signifies the end of string.  So by specifying it we are avoiding any other matches of space followed by digits (if there are) while removing